# Is transform:perspective only for 3d elements?

Tags: css

**TLDR**

[In this exercise](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/CSS/transform/perspective.html) I am trying out, applying different `transform: perspective(d);` values to four different `div's` does nothing.

So, my question is: is perspective only for elements that are already in the 3d plane?

[image]

Here is the code.

```css
body { width: 100%; }
div {
font-family: Geneva, 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 4em;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
transform: perspective(-100cm);
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
transform: perspective(10cm);
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
transform: perspective(100cm);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>transform: perspective(-100cm);</div>
<div>No perspective.</div>
<div>transform: perspective(10cm);</div>
<div>transform: perspective(100cm);</div>
</body>
```

But all elements in a 2d plane are also in a 3d plane. Does perspective not apply to elements that are only in 2d space and have no `z-axis` value (either by rotating or skewing them or applying a 3d transform on them first)?

**Background**

I do understand what perspective means, both in the context of CSS *and* since I also take pictures, in the context of photography. They're not quite separate concepts in either contexts.

Per my understanding, in CSS, perspective makes an object appear closer or further away from the user by manipulating the magnitude of the `z-axis`, which is what we specify to the `perspective` function.

In photography, too, perspective determines the closeness of the object from the viewer of the picture. This is done by adjusting the focal length of the lens. If we use a tall/telephoto lens that has a high focal length, and we zoom in, then even objects that are actually far away appear to be closer and the background becomes compressed. When we use a wider lens, objects tend to push themselves further away from the user.

Comment: Your elements have z = 0 without applying a 3d transform to them: `Each 3D element with z>0 becomes larger; each 3D-element with z<0 becomes smaller` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Comment: @Adam Funny how I've been using the same guide on MDN and read that sentence several times and misunderstood it only until you pointed it out just now. Turns out my assumption that perspective applies only to 3d elements is indeed true. Could you please put that down as an answer?